# Icon does not appear in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, pyqt6

I'm making a clipboard that can save multiple items. My clipboard using `QClipboard` can store text, file paths and images. When you copy something it is shown in a `QTableWidget` but there is a problem with images. I want to show them in small size as an icon in a `QTableWidgetItem`, so my code converts the `QImage` to a `QPixmap` to a `QIcon` and places it in a `QTableWidgetItem`; however the cell is shown empty.

I can't figure out where the problem lies but maybe someone can spot it. The Placement in the table is executed by the "ToTable"-function.

```
class mainUI(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("MCInterface.ui", self)
        self.qcb = QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard()
        self.clipboard = []
        self.qcb.dataChanged.connect(self.GetClipboard)

    def GetClipboard(self):
        spinbox = self.ui.SB_ContainerLen
        clen = spinbox.value()

        if not self.ui.TB_Pause.isChecked():
            if self.qcb.text():
                data = self.qcb.text()
            elif self.qcb.image():
                data = (self.qcb.image())
            if data not in self.clipboard and len(self.clipboard) < clen:
                if isinstance(data, str) and data.startswith("file:///") and "\n" in data:
                    data = data.splitlines()
                    for d in data:
                        if len(self.clipboard) < clen:
                            self.clipboard.append(d)
                            self.ToTable(d)
                else:
                    self.clipboard.append(data)
                    self.ToTable(data)
            print(self.clipboard)

    def addRow(self):
        row = self.ui.TW_Clipboard.rowCount()
        self.ui.TW_Clipboard.insertRow(row)
        return row

    def ToTable(self, data):
        table = self.ui.TW_Clipboard

        if isinstance(data, QImage):
            row = self.addRow()
            pixmap = QPixmap()
            pixmap.fromImage(data)
            icon = QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(pixmap)
            xItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            xItem.setIcon(icon)
            yItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Bild")
            table.setItem(row, 0, xItem)
            table.setItem(row, 1, yItem)
        elif isinstance(data, str) and data.startswith("file:///"):
            row = self.addRow()
            table.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data[8:]))
            table.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Datei"))
        else:
            row = self.addRow() 
            table.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data))
            table.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Text"))
        
        table.setRowHeight(row, 50)
```

Comment: `xItem.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap.fromImage(data)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fromImage()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fromImage) is a *static* function that *returns* a QPixmap. Since you only executed the function without referencing its result, the `pixmap` is still the *empty* pixmap you created with `pixmap = QPixmap()`.
Change to the following:

```
    def ToTable(self, data):
        table = self.ui.TW_Clipboard

        if isinstance(data, QtGui.QImage):
            row = self.addRow()
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(data)
            # ...
```

<sup>Note that if you want to keep track of copied paths, you should use the mime data [`urls()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#urls) instead of converting them from text: copying an actual path is *not* the same of copying the string of that path.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about that although it's a common mistake I make. I'll also try to use mime data for file paths.